# Leaflet - I cannot seem to get the basic examples working

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I have been trying to get Leaflet (a webmapping API) working for hours.  At first I made the mistake of trying to do too much, now I am just trying to get the basic examples working.

Here's the code that I have (HTML and Javascript):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="./leaflet.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./leaflet.css" />  
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initmap(){
                var map1 = L.map('map');
                //map1.setView([38.642433, -90.255372]),9); //Thanks!
                map1.setView([38.642433, -90.255372],9);

                // add an OpenStreetMap tile layer
                L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                        attribution: '&amp;copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                }).addTo(map1);
            }
        </script>
       <style>
            #map {
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              right: 0;
              left: 0;
              bottom: 0;
              top: 0;
              z-index: 0;
            }
    </style>
        <!-- Without this styling to set the map dimension, the tiles will get downloaded, but nothing will display on the map div!  Thank you choz for answering this question!  -->
    </head>

    <body onload="initmap()">
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Summary:  I was at first getting "missing ; before statement" and "Reference Error:  initmap not defined".  That was fixed by removing the extra parenthesis in the map definition, per choz's first comment.
Then I had a problem with the maps not showing up, even though the tiles were being downloaded.  Choz commented again about the needed style for the map.  I included the working code above.

Comment: `map1.setView([38.642433, -90.255372]),9);` to `map1.setView([38.642433, -90.255372],9);`.

Comment: Wow.  Can't believe I didn't see that.  Went to a Code Until Dawn meetup Friday, maybe I'm just lacking sleep.

Comment: Now I get no errors, but nothing shows up, which is really weird, because if I press F12 for developer tools and go to the network tab, I see all the appropriate tile images have been downloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably forgot to set the dimension of your `#map`. Here's a very basic sample how you get it working.

```js
// create a map in the "map" div, set the view to a given place and zoom
var map = L.map("map").setView([39.50, -98.35], 5);

// add an OpenStreetMap tile layer
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
```

```css
#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out twice choz, and your final answer actually solved a problem I've had for days.

Comment: I'm updating the question with the final code layout.

Comment: This gets me every time, even after years of doing projects with maps. Everything is set but you see nothing. Usually it's simple dimensions needed.